# how to redirect bootstrap cancel button in cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a cancel button and I want to redirect on everything.ctp page and I have also a function everything() in  ApplicationsController. Below is cancel button code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary ">
   <a href="" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I have just give the url in href. Check below code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary ">
  <a href="http://localhost:7777/eman_test/applications/everything" 
    class="btn btn-info">Cancel</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think it's not the best idea. After deploying it on server, or moving application anywhere this link will expire. @Khattu Developer pointed good example.

Answer (score 0):

It's more preferable to do it in "CakePHP" way:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('submit', ['type'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary']);
    echo $this->Html->link(__('Cancel', ['controller' => 'Applications', 'action' => 'everything'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'escape' => false]);
   ?>
</div>
```